# how to locate the datafile path on a particular server (with 2 instances) for a particular instance?

Tags: oracle11g, server, instances, data-files

I am running Oracle 11g on Windows 7 machine. I have a server (suppose hostname:xyzabc2129) with 2 instances on it, one is called obcd_dev and other is called obcd_prod. I have created a tablespace and eventually a table and uploaded the data on the instance obcd_dev and I want to replicate the same process on obcd_prod instance. To replicate the same, I will need to locate the *.dbf or datafile for instance obcd_prod, and I do not know how to locate the same to create a new tablespace. I had received the datafile path name for obcd_dev from one of my co-workers and in his absence I need to locate the same for obcd_prod. Help is much appreciated. Explanation: I am looking for the following path in "'  '"->

```
CREATE TABLESPACE abcdedfgh DATAFILE 
             '/data/u01/blah/blah1/blah2.dbf' SIZE 2M
              AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M MAXSIZE 27648M
              LOGGING
              PERMANENT
              EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE
              BLOCKSIZE 8K
              SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
              FLASHBACK ON
```

Comment: `select * from dba_data_files` will tell you

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks a lot  for your quick reply. Indeed, it listed all of the datafile path, file_id, tablespace_name etc, solved my problem.